# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar datos de una cadena con Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Hola estoy desarrollando un proyecto Web con Firebase y no logro mostrar los datos de una cadena numérica... lo que quiero es cargar la url almacenada en mi base de datos de varias imágenes a un img para de esa manera alimentar un slider de imágenes, esta es la estructura de mi base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

preguntas:

1.- ¿cómo accedo a la cadena imágenes?.
2.- ¿cómo obtengo la url de cada item de la cadena?.

He leído la documentación de firebase pero no encuentro la forma estaré agradecido si alguien puede ayudarme ...

saludos

Comment: Te recomiendo que muestres el código que no funciona para que te podamos decir donde esta el error, y asi no lo cometas en un futuro

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder a los datos de cada url podrias hacer lo siguiente

```
firebase.database().ref().child("parques").child(uid).child("imagenes").on('value', function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
var datos = child.val();
var url  = child.val().url;
  });
});
```

`child(uid)` es el push o el userid que tenes despues de parques

Comment: hola sabes sigo estancado con esto probé tu respuesta pero el problema es que me sigue apareciendo todas las imágenes juntas no por registro intenté usando un condicionador pero no me da resultado te pasare el código para ver si puedes ayudarme por favor estaré muy agradecido .

Comment: he intentado enviar el código y no se como no me permite en el comentario

Comment: dentro  de la función que me enviaste como obtengo el uid de cada array para ponerlo en una variable???

Comment: podes usar el getKey() para obtener el padre de cada uno

Comment: Gracias lo he solucionado ....

Comment: Si pudiste solucionar el problema, podrias marcar la respuesta como correcta? Gracias